# Qual a melhor tradução de "picuínha" para inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês

No sentido de pirraça, procurar minúcias para criticar algo.

Do dicionário:

> Significado de Picuinha
>
> substantivo feminino
>
> <s>1. O primeiro pipilar da ave.</s>
>   <s>2. Remoque, caçoada.</s>
>   3. Coisa que se faz por implicância, como provocação, para aborrecer alguém.

Eu estou inclinado a usar "nitpicking":

> nitpick or nit-pick [ nit-pik ]
>
> verb (used without object)
>
> to be excessively concerned with or critical of inconsequential details.
>
> verb (used with object)
>
> to criticize by focusing on inconsequential details.
>   noun
>   a carping, petty criticism.

Algum termo melhor?

Comment: O ponto 3, é bem traduzido por "obnoxious". E o "nitpick" anda de mão dada com o "cherrypick". Mas pode ser um falso "picuinha", que afinal é "meticuloso" e "minucioso", "consciencioso". Depende do caso, o substantivo pode até nem ter substância.

Comment: Acho que devias incluir na pergunta uma frase em que uses a palavra.

Comment: Qual dicionário? O priberam [tem 5 significados](https://dicionario.priberam.org/picuinha); e o significado primário que eu dou à palavra não está na tua lista de significados: «Pormenor sem importância. = NINHARIA»

Comment: @aneves o dicionario utilizado é irrelevante o significado desejado existe nos outros e está realçado.

Comment: Picuinha is not nitpicking. Nitpicking assumes prior interaction or action. It is used after some other thing has happened.  If you do something to annoy someone, you are, in fact, being aggressive. You are picking a fight with them.

Comment: @Lambie I would just like to add, that in Portugal I've never seen the word "picuinha" being used with the heavily negative connotation the dictionary definitions seem to suggest. Words derived with the diminutive suffix "-inho/a" have a "familiar/friendly/childish" connotation, and the use of the word "picuinha" as I've seen it, is always taken as a friendly and benign remark. (With its meaning more diffuse/fuzzy than necessarily objective in definition.)

Comment: @bad_coder Acho que nessa altura do campeonato, uma aula de português desse jeito seria melhor para aqueles que estão por fora....:)

Comment: Mindwin, por favor, as palavras se traduzem em contexto.

Comment: A sample sentence, with context, would be welcome. Leave blanks where the word would be used.

Answer (score 4):

As melhores traduções que conheço para o substantivo `picuinha` são <kbd>nagging</kbd> e <kbd>bugging</kbd>.

`Picuinha` é o **persistente** (contínuo, ininterrupto, repetitivo, reiterado) **aborrecimento** (irritação, incomodação, implicância, aporrinhação) **inconveniente** (e às vezes intencional) que uma pessoa causa (provoca) por um motivo pequeno, **fútil**, irrelevante. Portanto, estes são os 4 requisitos para se dizer que existe uma "picuinha" em andamento: é necessário que se trate de um gesto <kbd>1</kbd> persistente (contínuo, reiterado, repetitivo), <kbd>2</kbd> irritante (incômodo, aborrecedor), <kbd>3</kbd> inconveniente (inoportuno, indevido, inadequado para o momento) e <kbd>4</kbd> por motivo besta, pequeno, fútil, irrelevante, irrisório, insignificante demais para merecer causar esse incômodo todo.

<kbd>Nagging</kbd> também é o **persistente** (contínuo, ininterrupto, repetitivo, reiterado) **aborrecimento** (irritação, incomodação, implicância, aporrinhação) **inconveniente** (e às vezes intencional) que uma pessoa causa (provoca) por um motivo pequeno, **fútil**, irrelevante. Exemplo: se o seu vizinho não vai com sua cara (ou vai com a sua cara mas não tem educação nem consideração pelos outros) e fica intencionalmente escutando música barulhenta durante todas as madrugadas (diariamente), então *he's <kbd>nagging</kbd> you* ("ele está de `picuinha` com você"), porque a atitude desse vizinho é persistente (ele faz isso todas as madrugadas), aborrecedora (ele incomoda você com barulhos), inconveniente (os barulhos ocorrem nos períodos em que você está dormindo ou tentando dormir) e fútil (porque a atitude dele não é útil, não é necessária, não é relevante, não tem conteúdo, não é construtiva etc.).

Escrever *he's <kbd>bugging</kbd> you* ("ele está incomodando você") é muito similar: assim como <kbd>nagging</kbd> (o ato de propositalmente incomodar de maneira persistente e fútil), <kbd>bugging</kbd> refere-se ao ato de incomodar alguém de maneira persistente. A pequena diferença é que no caso de <kbd>bugging</kbd> não é mandatório que a incomodação seja fútil nem intencional.

Quando se diz `ficar de picuinha` (com função de locução verbal, ou seja: no sentido de "ficar incomodando", "ficar aborrecendo", "ficar perturbando" etc.), além de <kbd>nagging</kbd> e <kbd>bugging</kbd> também se pode usar <kbd>driving (someone) mad</kbd>. Exemplo: *"She's <kbd>driving him mad</kbd>."* = "Ela está deixando ele doido" (de raiva).

Quando `ficar de picuinha` é usado no sentido de "ficar com frescura" (ser excessivamente/exageradamente seletivo/a, ficar implicando com / reclamando de tudo: implicando com a / reclamando da comida, implicando com o / reclamando do calor que está fazendo etc.), é mais comum dizer-se <kbd>being picky</kbd>. Exemplo: *He's <kbd>being picky</kbd> with everything: the food, weather, temperature... Everything!* = "Ele está de picuinha com tudo: a comida, a temperatura, o clima... Tudo!".

Comment: O problema é que isso "Portanto, estes são os 4 requisitos para se dizer que existe uma "picuinha" em andamento", não tem tradução sem o contexto de uma frase. Dizer que picuinha é nagging e bugging me parece possível em alguns contextos e impossível em outros. "Ela está deixando ele doido" é pêssima gramática, né?

Comment: @Lambie *Péssima gramática* como? Não entendi. Em relação a os 4 requisitos não terem tradução sem o contexto de uma frase, essa é a raiz do problema e é algo inerente à pergunta feita (não à resposta que dei). Digo: certamente não existe uma resposta universal, que plenamente traduza a palavra `picuinha` para o inglês em todos os contextos possíveis. As traduções que citei são as formas que mais frequentemente vejo serem usadas, mas elas não esgotam o assunto (eu não aleguei isso). Outras pessoas podem adicionar outras respostas. Juntas, todas as respostas hão de responder melhor que uma.

Answer (score 1):

For what I was looking for, ***nitpick***  seems to be the correct one. I found an example in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nitpicked):

> to find faults in details that are not important:
> ● *You're always nitpicking - it's so annoying!*

Comment: Syvia, bem-vinda à comunidade. Formatei a tua resposta e linkei ao dicionário. Vê se gostas.

Answer (score 0):

Depende, obviamente, do contexto mas **nit-pick** ou simplismente **picky** traduções muito próximas do termo português, até porque ambas são expressões mais coloquiais.

Algumas alternativas a **picky** igualmente adequadas, dependendo do contexto, seriam:

1. ***fussy:*** *"make a fuss over nothing"* significa fazer muito barulho/confusão por algo de nada (ou fazer uma tempestade num copo de água); alguém *fussy* seria alguém que "só sabe implicar", portanto, irritante/inconveniente/exagerado;
2. ***chooser/choosy:*** existe a expressão inglesa *"beggers can't be choosers/choosy"*, que se traduz para *"mendigos não podem ser picuinhas"*, ou seja, não podem ter grandes exigências.

Outras palavras com um significado próximo ***selective, finicky*** ou ***squeamish***, mas, mais uma vez, ***picky*** é provavelmente a melhor tradução.